# How to manage large project forks

Tags: git

I forked a large project using git and it becomes unmanageable for me after many people commit their changes.  I usually find that I have to delete my fork, then fork the initial repo again if I want to keep my code up to date.

What is the proper way to keep a project fork (copy) without regularly deleting it only to fork again?

Comment: In what way does it become unmanageable?

Answer (score 1):

We use Git at work with large projects and multiple developers. The best way we've found to keep the merge overhead down is to keep commits small, merge them into your master branch frequently, and update your feature branch by merging the updated code from master as soon as it becomes available. Having many, large branches at the same time definitely makes merging more complicated.

For reference, there's lots of information out there about the "Git Flow" and other alternative ways of using Git. In general, though, recommendations tend to boil down to keeping master up-to-date, and not allowing your feature branches to fall too far behind the main line.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the original remote repository as a remote so that you are upto date with the lastest changes.

```
git remote add upstream < ORIGINAL REPO URL >
```

Fetch from the original repository everyday, so that you do not lag behind.

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/yourbranch
```